# How to get PlotBands data to show up on HighChart chart?

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/627yamt2/

Docs: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/plot-bands-and-plot-lines

Trying to get plotbands to show up, however no luck so far, what am I missing?

This is the only code I added to the forked jsfiddle above:

```
xAxis: {
  dateTimeLabelFormats: {hour: '%I %p', minute: '%I:%M %p'},
  plotBands: [{
       color: 'red',
       from: 1,
       to: 2,
       value: 3, // Value of where the line will appear
       width: 2, // Width of the line   
       label: { 
            text: 'I am a label', // Content of the label. 
            align: 'left' // Positioning of the label. 
       }
  }]
},
```

Trying to get something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think that your plotBands have wrong parameters. Here you can see an example of plotBand with your data http://jsfiddle.net/627yamt2/1/

Comment: Thanks, but damn it still can't get this to show up in my real app :(

Comment: Ok want to post your answer? Btw this works for me now in my real app :D `chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({`

Comment: I have posted my answer. It is weird that it is not working with your real app, but I am happy that you have find a solution for this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you need to use parameters connected with plotBands. Right now some of your parameters are connected with plotLines as well and I think this is causing your issue. Here you can find parameters for plotBands:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands

```
    plotBands: [{
      color: 'red',
      from: 1265888000000,
      to: 1345888000000,
      label: {
        text: 'I am a label', // Content of the label. 
        align: 'left' // Positioning of the label. 
      }
    }]
```

And here you can find live example how your chart can look with plotBands:
http://jsfiddle.net/627yamt2/1/

You can also add plotBands using xAxis.addPlotBand method:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.addPlotBand

Best regards.

Comment: Hey man thanks again for the answer! Have you ever run into this before? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616712/how-to-hide-highchart-plotline-label-until-mouseover